# Which java webframework for high performance and scalability

Tags: model-view-controller, performance

I have to design a java based web application, it should support be highly scalable, should support almost 500 concurrent users with response time less than 3 secs. I have short listed 5 frameworks(Struts, Spring MVC, JSF, Wicket and GWT).  My questions are:

1.I want to compare the performance of these framworks similar to the way it described in below
  (this is between JSF and Wicket). Are there any resources for other frameworks?
  http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/seam-jsf-vs-wicket-performance-comparison/

2.Apart from above mentioned frameworks, are there any framweworks I should consider?

Comment: See also: [Choosing a Java Web Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now)

Comment: With average workload and a half-decent server, I suspect any framework that can't handle 500 users in under 3 secs is very bloated.

Comment: you have missed out "Spring roo" http://www.springsource.org/roo.

Answer (score -1):

@goutham you have missed out "HybridJava". As of presentation layer itself (and this technology is about presentation layer only) it gives about 1 ms CPU per page.